# D/FirebaseInstanceId: background sync failed: INVALID_PARAMETERS

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Tried to register a token using FCM, the connection is OK, but I get the following error:

```
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 13635 on device emulator-5554
D/FirebaseInstanceId: background sync failed: INVALID_PARAMETERS, retry in 10s
D/FirebaseInstanceId: background sync failed: INVALID_PARAMETERS, retry in 20s
```

Comment: check in real device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had same issue and I have solved it by just adding below code in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<application android:label="My APP Name" android:icon="@mipmap/icon">


<receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
<receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Tried both suggestions here and still getting the same issue. Anything else I should be checking?

Answer (score 1):

Remember to make the installation clean. Had similar issue and I have solved it by uninstalling and relaunch it on real device. Firebase needs to register the device at first launch.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was subscribing/unsubscribing using for loop, which did not work for async firebase tasks.

```
for (var item in items) {
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('topic');
}
```

The solution was to change to `map`

```
items.map((item) {
      FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('topic');
    }).toList();
```